# Testing string for repeated alphanumeric characters in bash with regex

Tags: regex, bash

I have a string "AbCdEfGG" and I need to test if there are repeated alphanumeric using regex in bash. This is the code I am using right now.

```
# Check if the password contains a repeated alphanumeric character 
if [[ "$password_to_test" =~ ([a-zA-Z0-9])\1{2,} ]]; then
  let score=score-10
  echo "Password contains a repeated alphanumeric character (-10 points)"
else
  echo "Password does not contain a repeated alphanumeric character"
fi
```

But it never decrements 10 from the score. I need help with the regex pattern here.

Comment: Off course it will not match since `AbCdEfGG` is NOT having any numeric values, it is pure alphabets only.

Comment: Please mention `repeated alphanumeric` what it is in your post too with proper example please?

Comment: Alphanumeric includes both numbers and letters of the alphabet and I gave the example of "AbCdEfGG". Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BASH regex doesn't support back-reference on all the platforms as it depends on underlying system's regex library ERE implementation (Thanks to @ BenjaminW).

You may use this `grep`:

```
str='AbCdEfGG'

if grep -Eq '([[:alnum:]])\1' <<< "$str"; then
   ((score -= 10))
   echo "Password contains a repeated alphanumeric character (-10 points)"
else
   echo "Password does not contain a repeated alphanumeric character"
fi
```

It is better to use POSIC bracket expression `[[:alnum:]]` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: I think he wrote `alphanumeric`. And used quantifier `{2,}` by mistake.

Comment: Backreference support depends on the underlying system's regex library ERE implementation - some do support backreferences.

Comment: That's a good point @BenjaminW. I will make a note in my answer.